# How to display user email on the Google Web App

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google web app in order to build simply HTML which inserting some informations filled by user to google sheet (apps script application is hosted in a Google Apps Enterprise account). What I'm trying to do is display user e-mail at HTML Page by using `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` method. Could you please advise me how can I do it?

This is my code.gs:

```
    function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page.html").evaluate();
    }
    
    function userClicked(userInfo){
    
      var url ="path";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var ws = ss.getSheetByName("BAZA");
      var l_row = ws.getLastRow() + 1
      
        ws.getRange(l_row,1).setValue(userInfo.RANK)
```

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <?!= include("page-css.html"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2">
    <select id="RANK">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz rank </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Rank</label>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     <?!= include("page-js.html"); ?>

**HERE SHOULD BE USER ADDRESS EMAIL**

  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    <script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",clickedBtn);
    
    function clickedBtn(){
    
      var responseInfo = {};

      responseInfo.RANK = document.getElementById("RANK").value;
      google.script.run.userClicked(responseInfo);

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a template (`createTemplateFromFile`) you could replace

```
**HERE SHOULD BE USER ADDRESS EMAIL**
```

by

```
<?= Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() ?>
```

In order to this to work, you should set to web application to be executed as the user who is accessing it.

[image]

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)